# css 3d rotate safari / chrome bug

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-transforms

I am trying to create a house with an opening door svg animation. I tried for hours to get the same result on firefox, safari, chrome. But it seems I cannot get it to work on safari, see the snippet below. I want the door to open like in the image with a pointed angle at the bottom.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

svg {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f2f;
  stroke: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 100% 0;
  perspective-origin: 100% 0;
}

#door {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 180px center;
  transform-origin: 180px center;
  fill: #fff;
}

svg:hover #door{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
  transform: rotateY(-45deg);;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <g id="door">
              <rect id="door-rect" x="120" y="100" width="60" height="100" />
              <circle id="door-handle" cx="130" cy="150" r="5" />
            </g>
  </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware only Firefox currently supports 3d animation of SVG elements via CSS

Comment: for me it works fine in window's chrome , not firefox that keeps it flat

Comment: so where do i find information about that 3d animation of svg elements? If this is the issue i can find another way i hope

Answer (score 2):

Add a skewY to make the upward movement.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

svg {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f2f;
  stroke: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 100% 0;
  perspective-origin: 100% 0;
}

#door {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 180px center;
  transform-origin: 180px center;
  fill: #fff;
}

svg:hover #door{
  transform: rotateY(-45deg) skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <g id="door">
              <rect id="door-rect" x="120" y="100" width="60" height="100" />
              <circle id="door-handle" cx="130" cy="150" r="5" />
            </g>
  </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: that fixes it for firefox , but for chrome it increases the skew/3d effect ...

Comment: Interesting. On my Mac it looks the same on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: okay, i'll check my updates , i'm gona believe somedays that a browser hacker ghost is messing around in  my computer.

Comment: Maybe it's my systems that are screwed up. Who knows? I still don't know why we can't have consistency across all browsers. If nothing else the differences could be "fixed" with prefixes.

Comment: I have the same feeling, but my 10 year old computer might not be the cleaner you could find and trust .. (W7) about to be thrown away

Comment: I use this hack now, but it would be appreciated to know where the "bug" comes from. Is it safari user agent style sheets and things that can be overridden in css or safari not supporting svg 3d tranfsofrm. happy for more information